# Error 1 libavcodec.so File format not recognized Android GL Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, live-wallpaper

I am trying to make a Live Wallpaper for android that plays an .mp4 video located on the device in android-asset (with the example I am using, it actually copies the file to the sdcard at runtime/doesn't matter)

I found this [example](https://github.com/frankandrobot/GLWallpaperVideoDemo) 
And using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256412/how-to-play-video-as-live-wallpaper-android) I was able to get my eclipse set up with NDK and building the project.
When building in eclipse using the NDK plugin I get this error in my problems window:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [libs/armeabi/libavcodec.so] Error 1  GLWallpaperVideoDemo-master         C/C++ Problem
make: *** Deleting file `libs/armeabi/libavcodec.so'    GLWallpaperVideoDemo-master         C/C++ Problem
```

I get the same error if I try to run `ndk-build` from command prompt.

I downloaded the project from the link above and then imported into eclipse. I added the lib GLWallpaperService to the build path, and made sure my NDK was setup. Knowing that the lib folder changed to libs I also tried moving the GLWallpaperService to the libs folder, which didn't help.

The project builds without NDK just fine in eclipse but obviously errors when trying to run the wallpaper because the native libraries were not built.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

The package you get by `git clone https://github.com/frankandrobot/GLWallpaperVideoDemo.git` is Linux oriented. The file `jni\ffmpeg-android\build\ffmpeg\armeabi\lib\libavcodec.so` and many others are simply symbolic links to actual files.

To make this all work easily on Windows, I suggest to go to the `jni\ffmpeg-android\build\ffmpeg\armeabi\lib` folder, and run

```
del *.so
copy libavcodec.so.52.99.1 libavcodec.so
copy libavcore.so.0.16.0 libavcore.so
copy libavdevice.so.52.2.2 libavdevice.so
copy libavfilter.so.1.69.0 libavfilter.so
copy libavformat.so.52.88.0 libavformat.so
copy libavutil.so.50.34.0 libavutil.so
copy libswscale.so.0.12.0 libswscale.so
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be because of a corrupted so file. Try to build the ffmpeg library again or find another version. Because I have a different error in eclipse when I try to compile the project:

> C:/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip:./libs/armeabi/libavcodec.so: **File format not recognized**

And when I search for this error it seems like the error is because of a corrupted file: [NDK prebuilt shared library file format not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680502/ndk-prebuilt-shared-library-file-format-not-recognized)

Or the library is not in a format that Android can use:
[Error in linking C++ static library with android ndk(Error: file format not recognized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311874/error-in-linking-c-static-library-with-android-ndkerror-file-format-not-reco/8312255#8312255)

Comment: You actually see the same error message, you only filter it differently.

Comment: Yes I have the same error message but you did not include this important part in your question.